# CSS - changing fixed width to a calculated width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can I legitimately change a CSS width using JS from

```
width: 100%
```

to:

```
width: calc(100% - 180px);
```

i.e. will the CSS3 calc function work after JS has inserted it into the attribute?

There are probably better ways of doing this (float etc), but this is due to the appearance of a left navbar. Also will this work with JQuery methods for setting width?

Comment: `will the CSS3 calc function work after JS has inserted it into the attribute?` Couldn't you test it?! Ya, it works! Doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: It is often useful to post questions on here, even if I can find the answer quickly, because alternative ideas crop up. In this case, I'm not entirely happy with use of calc so a range of replies is helpful

Comment: That's a correct point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee `$().width('calc()')` compatibility, but it should work if you directly set it as the width style.

`$('myselector').css('width','calc(100% - 180px)');`

But is there any reason you can't put it directly in the CSS?

Comment: At a certain point in the application, a menu bar appears to the left of screens that previously didn't have one. I am trying to keep changes to the code/css to a minimum instead of giving in to the temptation to restyle everything... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should approach this by other means. Here are some options:

- Set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the element and add a 180px padding on the left.
- Give the content wrapper (not containing the navigation bar) a left padding of 180px.

*Note: [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) is arguably a preferable property for all elements, since it doesn't mess up your widths when setting paddings and borders.*

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
Some of the browsers not support calc(); so please try following jquery 
$('your id').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=100px');
```